# block popups from iframe/embed

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, alert, system-alert-window

I have a lot of iframes and they are from spotify and I keep getting pop ups that ask for the content of the device which will cause one embed/iframe to pause when another one stops. How can I get all the iframes to not allow popups? This is just a small snippet of what I have:

my site can be found here: https://50izac02.github.io/sb/music.html

```js
<script>
        var songs1 = [
    "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1K9QXJtypYRMVrfHixmHh3",
 "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/7clyJIrLkEbXUDwj1tC9zz", 
 "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/0AB5CTb04eqXnV9hEZx9FL",
  "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/31G6jTLEpHwGs3vpQ7iUJM"];
document.getElementById("spot1").src = songs1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0];

var songs2 = [
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/1BlqKx3JtMKY3K6F0uUbqW",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/7h2yzh9vIBxSBN3885QyQt",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/4EAV2cKiqKP5UPZmY6dejk",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5dqrgmHHBuUzwYKBXJuIm0"
];
document.getElementById("spot2").src = songs2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0];
    
    var songs3 = [
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5dqrgmHHBuUzwYKBXJuIm0",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/6QyBWey7P8ILuhS5RO7xYe",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5qrSlOut2rNAWv3ubArkNy",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/0TN3FKCgNsck8Z0t463bU0",
    ];
    document.getElementById("spot3").src = songs3[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0];
    
    var songs4 = [
        "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5IcpFfoUZLU3G7b8BtppFi",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/4R8RG1OWtp0ahfyGUcD76M",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/6IHWepcSxwLdzM38nQSrnC",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/6JyuJFedEvPmdWQW0PkbGJ",];
 document.getElementById("spot4").src = songs4[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0];

var songs5 = [
 "https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/41n0s0MdHk3SQYrJ4djpXb",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/3uKxSYyWgMqu9LrgC2Lo7v",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/0e9yz3Fz7Nn6I5E4XBP8no",
"https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/4hPpVbbakQNv8YTHYaOJP4",
];
document.getElementById("spot5").src = songs5[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0];
```

```html
<div id="row 1">
        <iframe id="spot1" src="" width="250" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <iframe id="spot2" src="" width="250" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <iframe id="spot3" src="" width="250" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <iframe id="spot4" src="" width="250" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
        <iframe id="spot5" src="" width="250" height="90" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You could sandbox the iframe with: sandbox="allow-scripts". That should stop them from producing popups.

Comment: yes sorry i fixed this a long time ago lol my new site is http://soms.cf/

Comment: @50izac02 How did you block popups in iframes? I cant get over this